# I'm getting the same response html which I used to post parameters in httpclient

Tags: java, html, httpclient

I'm getting the same response HTML when I tried to post username and password parameters to login page. I have followed the tutorial that is present here.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

I'm able to successfully do this for gmail page but I'm unable to do this for the IBM Partner World Page. Here is my java program that I used for page login

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.CookieHandler;
    import java.net.CookieManager;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

    public class tt {

      private String cookies;
      private HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
      private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www-304.ibm.com/usrsrvc/account/userservices/jsp/login.jsp?persistPage=true&page=/partnerworld/wps/servlet/mem/ContentHandler/partnerworld-public%3Flnk%3Dleft-nav&PD-REFERER=https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/partnerworld-public&error=";
    String gmail = "https://www.ibm.com/partnerworld/page/X082763O18037G72";

    // make sure cookies is turn on
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    tt http = new tt();

    String page = http.GetPageContent(url);

    List<NameValuePair> postParams = 
               http.getFormParams(page, "username","password");

    http.sendPost(url, postParams);

    String result = http.GetPageContent(gmail);
    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.println("Done");
      }

     private void sendPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> postParams) 
        throws Exception {

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // add header
    post.setHeader("Host", "www-304.ibm.com:443");
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    post.setHeader("Accept", 
             "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    post.setHeader("Cookie", getCookies());
    post.setHeader("Accept-Encoding" ,"gzip,deflate,sdch");
    //post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    post.setHeader("Referer", "https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_com_jnw_index");
    //post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

     System.out.println(result.toString());

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    request.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36");
    request.setHeader("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    request.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    // set cookies
    setCookies(response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie") == null ? "" : 
                     response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie").toString());

    return result.toString();

  }

  public List<NameValuePair> getFormParams(
             String html, String username, String password)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    // Google form id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("login");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");

    List<NameValuePair> paramList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");

        if (key.equals("username"))
            value = username;
        else if (key.equals("password"))
            value = password;

System.out.println(username+password);
        paramList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));

    }

    return paramList;
  }

  public String getCookies() {
    return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(String cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
  }

}
```

I get the same HTML as response which is used to post parameters. Please help me with this.
I want to know How to login to this website and maintain my session.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I used chrome browser's developer tool and checked the different urls the browser is trying to get me through GET and POST requests.
Goto Dev Tools> Network > and try accessing the web page normally> You'll see all the information even the cookies and content that is returned from the site.
The forms varies from page to page that you want to mimic. You should check the source of the login page (and different forms in it) that you want to mimic. Use the proper form where the username and password is being sent.
Also when you monitor the webpage requests using dev tools. check all entities. I got my problems fixed by
 1. Checking the encoded form of password. UrlEncodedFormEntity is different what my browser is using.
  `return "login-form-type=pwd&username="+username+"&password="+password;`
 
2. And the exact form url which is actually responsible for sending the parameters.And also the next page after login parameters are sent.

```
String url = "https://www-304.ibm.com/pkmslogin.form";
String gmail = "https://www.ibm.com/partnerworld/page/X082763O18037G72";
```

Also make sure that you store the cookies and send them back for the next request. Because this is how you maintain a session.